# how to divide one amount into 5 product by given a percentage in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have 2 data Frame as below DF1 and DF2

DF1: I am importing this from an Excel file.

```
 DF1 
  Product             % to be applied in Exp
0   00028                  0.1080
1   00031                  0.2067
2   00045                  0.3469
3   00089                  0.1877
4   00099                  0.1507
5   Total                  1.0000
```

[image]

DF2 : I am importing this from an Excel file which contains thousand of Expanses details. How ever i am only taking 3 rows for my calculation.

```
 DF2
   Account    CC Account Dis  Exp Amount
0   523761  US12   Admin Exp    50000.12
1   578212  9999  Travle Exp    89673.89
2   578511  0234       Rent     50202.99
```

Out put :I want out put as below. each row of Exp Amount of DF2 must be splited by each product by its % from DF1. Is there any way around to solve this calculations ?

***Output***

```
>>> Output
    Account    CC Account Dis  Product    Exp Amount
0    523761  US12   Admin Exp       28   5400.012960
1    523761  US12   Admin Exp       31  10335.024804
2    523761  US12   Admin Exp       45  17345.041628
3    523761  US12   Admin Exp       89   9385.022524
4    523761  US12   Admin Exp       99   7535.018084
5    578212  9999  Travle Exp       28   9684.780120
6    578212  9999  Travle Exp       31  18535.593063
7    578212  9999  Travle Exp       45  31107.872441
8    578212  9999  Travle Exp       89  16831.789153
9    578212  9999  Travle Exp       99  13513.855223
10   578511  0234       Rent        28   5421.922920
11   578511  0234       Rent        31  10376.958033
12   578511  0234       Rent        45  17415.417231
13   578511  0234       Rent        89   9423.101223
14   578511  0234       Rent        99   7565.590593
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: @Yatin. I do understand . but the only i am not able to corelate how to do that .. i have imported both the dataFrame and able to do some calulations the only i thing not able to  do is my question .. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cross-join the two tables and multiply `Exp Amount` with `% to be applied in Exp`. Then just drop the irrelevant columns.

```
df1.drop(df1.index[df1['Product'] == 'Total'], inplace = True)
df1['Product'] = pd.to_numeric(df1["Product"])
df1['key'], df2['key'] = 1,1
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on = 'key').drop('key', 1)
df3['Exp Amount'] = df3['Exp Amount'].multiply(df3['% to be applied in Exp'])
df3.drop('% to be applied in Exp', 1, inplace = True)
df3 = df3.reindex(columns = ['Account', 'CC', 'Account Dis', 'Product', 'Exp Amount'])
df3
>>>
    Account    CC Account Dis  Product    Exp Amount
0    523761  US12   Admin Exp       28   5400.012960
1    523761  US12   Admin Exp       31  10335.024804
2    523761  US12   Admin Exp       45  17345.041628
3    523761  US12   Admin Exp       89   9385.022524
4    523761  US12   Admin Exp       99   7535.018084
5    578212  9999  Travle Exp       28   9684.780120
6    578212  9999  Travle Exp       31  18535.593063
7    578212  9999  Travle Exp       45  31107.872441
8    578212  9999  Travle Exp       89  16831.789153
9    578212  9999  Travle Exp       99  13513.855223
10   578511  0234        Rent       28   5421.922920
11   578511  0234        Rent       31  10376.958033
12   578511  0234        Rent       45  17415.417231
13   578511  0234        Rent       89   9423.101223
14   578511  0234        Rent       99   7565.590593
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. when i am running first code as df1['Product'] = pd.to_numeric(df1["Product"])   then i have error  "ValueError: Unable to parse string "Total" at position 5" ..not sure what is happening  with this . I hope you must consider abobe 2 DF ... DF1 and DF2 ... Please guied me .

Comment: Simply drop the row where `df1['Product'] == 'Total'`. Have updated my answer

Comment: ohh Yes,, I have fixed it.. This was beacuse of Total. Just another thing will the product  
be  with 4 disit as we have in the DF1. We have 2 disit in column Prodcut in Output df3. I am trying if function to change with 4 disit but if  you can do with same .. will be great MrSolo

Comment: You put 4 digits in your output. How many digits do you want? If you wish to leave it as 4 digits with leading zeroes, simply just don't convert the column to `int`

Comment: #MrSoLoDolo... WOW ..  you are excllente ... Thanks a ton for this ... now i am trying  calulating tax which 12 % on each amount with same details in df3. the only  Account Dis should be display Tax Exp . but i am failed but i am trying ...

Comment: Refer to my code on how I re-assigned `Exp Amount` as a column. The method is exactly the same.

Comment: Yes Super .. i already did .. thanks for this .. You are Excellete .....